# Retrieving only values from a column in R

Tags: r, regex, dataframe

Hi I have the dataset with column as below, I need only the values. Please suggest how to go about it

Input :

```
Col1

45.90625 %RH
491.25 ppm
523.5 ppm
0 % open
58.59375 cfm
50 deg F
24.3125 % open
0 % open
55.59375 deg F
0 % open
70 deg F
```

Output :

```
 Col1

45.90625
491.25 
523.5 
0 
58.59375 
50 
24.3125 
0 
55.59375 
0 
70
```

Comment: `sapply(strsplit(df$Col1, " "), '[[', 1)` ?

Comment: don´t forget to as.numeric() the results if you want them to be treated as a number.

Comment: Thanks, the above code is working. But if I try to convert to numerics, its throwing a warning, and really not chaning to numerics 

Warning message:
NAs introduced by coercion

Comment: Use `sub(" .*", "", df$Col1)`.

Comment: No, still NAs produced

Answer (score 1):

Try this regex:

```
^\d*(?:\.\d+)?
```

[Click for Demo](http://rubular.com/r/2F8JjYHDdW)

**Explanation:**

- `^` - asserts the start of the string
- `\d*` - matches 0+ digits
- `(?:\.\d+)?` - matches a `.` followed by 1+ digits. `?` in the end makes this sub-sequence optional

Answer (score 0):

You could capture the first occurence and then replace the value with this:

```
col1 <- c('45.90625 %RH', '491.25 ppm', '523.5 ppm', '0 % open', '58.59375 cfm', '50 deg F', '24.3125 % open', 
          '0 % open', '55.59375 deg F', '0 % open', '70 deg F')

gsub(".*?\\b(\\d+(?:\\.\\d+)?)\\b.*", "\\1", col1)
```

This yields

```
[1] "45.90625" "491.25"   "523.5"    "0"        "58.59375" "50"       "24.3125"  "0"        "55.59375" "0"       
[11] "70"
```

As numbers:

```
col1 <- c('45.90625 %RH', '491.25 ppm', '523.5 ppm', '0 % open', '58.59375 cfm', '50 deg F', '24.3125 % open', 
          '0 % open', '55.59375 deg F', '0 % open', '70 deg F')

(col2 <- as.numeric(gsub(".*?\\b(\\d+(?:\\.\\d+)?)\\b.*", "\\1", col1)))
```

Comment: it works, but when I try converting to numeric its producing NAs

Comment: @Anagha: Updated the answer. You might have problems with factors here (how are you constructing your dataframe?).

Comment: Yes, I figured out there are values in the column which are characters eg. "Alarm", "Occupied" etc. Hence these are being converted to NAs when applied "as.numeric"